# CSS to display three column content

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

I am trying to get three column output using `<div>` for each.

Right now my div on the left is lined properly even the middle one, but when I try to put right it is just clipping down.

**CSS**

```css
/* left div */
 #left-sidebar, #right-sidebar {
    width:15%;
    height:700px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

/* middle div */
 #mid-content {
    width:75%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

/* right div */
 #right-sidebar {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: your right div should be just 10% or less, specify it in your css

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your elemnents add up to 105% in all.
Second, you have added padding to a floating element which have a width specified in %, not a good idea. Look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Here is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/Ru6CL/

```css
#left-sidebar,
#right-sidebar,
#mid-content {
    float:left;
}

#left-sidebar,
#right-sidebar {
    width: 15%;
    background-color: red;
}
#mid-content {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

*remember to use* `clear: both;`

Comment: @KyleMit i did the modifications but still the right-sidebar clips down.. also please tell me where and how to use clear:both

Comment: @KyleMit should i use a table to place all the divs in each respective coloumns???? my left-sidebar contains a navigation panel like when we hover on it the sub navigation is floated left and then the mid-content and later again the right-sidebar...

Comment: You should never use tables for design purpose.
Tables are made for data.

Can you try to make a jsfiddle version of your page so we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the values to add up to 100%?. Right now, 75%, 15% and 15% adds up to 105%.

Comment: @AndrewEvt lol, another miscalculation in the same post :) thanks for the hint. I edited the answer.

Comment: manipulated my calculations.. got it under 100%.. but still the problem exist

Answer (score 0):

That happens because according to CSSs [box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/),  the size of the element is the sum of its width, border and padding thus - your content+padding exceeds the 100%.

in order to solve this, just add

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to your columns and it will recalculate the necessary width along with the above taken into consideration.

In addition, you might consider floating the elements to the same direction, i.e to the left since the box-sizing thing might get thrown off otherwise.

I made a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v6peK/

Comment: I wouldn't advice to use box-sizing, i know it's supported in all major browsers, but it's bad practice.

Comment: It's being endorsed by Paul Irish for almost two years now: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ and from personal experience - i beg to differ, however i do want to ask what makes you think so?

Comment: @arpymastro - i've update my answer and provided a working example.